# Asking somebody's name

Tags: word-usage

Is there any difference between Onamae wa and Anata no namae wa nan desu ka?

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between "Onamae wa" and "Anata no namae wa nan desu ka?" or the difference between "Onamae wa nan desu ka?" and "Anata no namae wa nan desu ka?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

お、です is polite form, so if you use them, the sentence become polite.

And only お名前は? can get across but I think (あなたの)お名前は何ですか? is more polite than it.

In addition お名前は何とおっしゃいますか? is more polite than お名前は何ですか?.

Answer (score 3):

お名前をうかがってもよろしいですか？ is more common when you work in the office.